# Cannot set property 'two' of undefined

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have the following code, but I'm lost on why I'm getting the error.  Each object is filled with a value, but where would I be getting an undefined?

`Cannot set property 'two' of undefined`

```
interface FakeObj {
  one: string | null;
  two: string | null;
  three: string | null;
}

const objectOne: FakeObj[] = [
  {
    one: null,
    two: "Two",
    three: null
  }
];

const objectTwo: FakeObj[] = [
  {
    one: "One",
    two: null,
    three: "Three"
  }
];

const newObject = objectOne.map((search, index) => {
  return Object.entries(search).reduce((acc, [key, value]) => {
    acc[key] = !value && objectTwo.length > index ? objectTwo[index][key] : value;
  }), {};
});

console.log(newObject);
```

**UPDATED**: Updated code, but now getting new issues:

`Cannot set property 'two' of undefined`

`Cannot create property 'two' on string 'One'`

Comment: Are you sure you couldn't do a few more things in that function? Don't try and do everything in a single line of code, split up your stuff, declare it neatly in separate rows and then you'll also way easier see what your problem is.

Comment: `= !value` should be `!== value`.

Comment: @lawrence-witt that is actually a ternary statement.

Comment: It's not doing what you think its doing. `= !value` assigns the negation of `value` to `acc[key]` - it does not assign either of your ternary conditions. You need to use `===` or `!==` to work with equality, `=` is for assigning value.

Comment: @lawrence-witt !value is being short for value === null

Comment: Ok my bad, I misread what you're going for.

Comment: No worries.  The main culprit is `acc[key as keyof CustomerList]`

Comment: What's `CustomerList`? Doesn't look like it has any keys

Comment: What is `CustomerList`?  Please consider modifying the code in this question so as to constitute a [mcve] which, when dropped into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link)](https://tsplay.dev/WkjkLm), clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  This will allow those who want to help you to immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  And it will make it so that any answer you get is testable against a well-defined use case.

Comment: @jcalz if you would like to see the original question that got me here, you can view: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68686085/how-to-merge-two-objects-containing-same-keys-but-different-values/68686368#68686368

Comment: I prefer to deal with self-contained questions containing a [mcve] I can start debugging directly.  If such code appears here I might take a look; otherwise maybe someone else can figure out how to help here.  Good luck!

Comment: I have rewritten the question so that you can run it locally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you, first of all, want to declare the objects as an array:

```
const objectOne: FakeObj[] = [
  {
    one: null,
    two: "Two",
    three: null
  }
];
```

Instead of `const objectOne: FakeObj`.

Then for the `undefined`, you are not returning anything from reduce, thus `acc` will be undefined on all but the first call.

You are also not returning inside your `map` thus the final log will be  `[undefined]`.

I *think* your code should be (although I haven't yet wrapped my head around what you are doing):

```js
const newObject = objectOne.map((search, index) => {
  return Object.entries(search).reduce((acc, [key, value]) => {
    acc[key] = !value && objectTwo.length > index ? objectTwo[index][key] : value;

    return acc;
  },{})
});

console.log(newObject);
```

### Answer to follow up question in the comments:

```js
const newObject = objectOne.map((search, index) => {
  return Object.entries(search).reduce((acc: FakeObj, [key, value]) => {
    acc[key as keyof FakeObj] = !value && objectTwo.length > index ? objectTwo[index][key as keyof FakeObj] : value;

    return acc;
  },{one: null, two: null, three: null})
});
```

Comment: Well, I have code that I was trying to work with, but I can't show it so I had to make something generic to figure out my issue.  However, when I use this code, I now get `No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{}'`.  That's coming from `acc[key]`.

Comment: @pingeyeg go checkout https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGJwNYQPICMBWyA3gFDLID2IEAXMgM5hSgDmyAPsiAK4A2vAbjLIwAdwp1GzEG049+Q8mAAWUCLQZNWHLn0EkAviRIIqjSgQgIw2anXRY8+ANoBdZAF5kz4aXLkqDXleABphJXE6ACIAFXEosP8RVXU6YOEjVyETMzALfCswOIk0TBwCN09vX3DKO2Qo2wgE2rES4MT-FTUNWJTmjJIs41MQc2pRJ0KqiktrJoA6AFs4AAcACnX6CDgoBGUQ5FAAEwgADwBKTwA+YmE1MG4oEGQp6wWIcGYIei2dveUFwWamO3CQm0QCEOziwAE9DgA3OC8bgQVxXDy3Pz+SEwiCw9xeACESJRKAAZOT8oVigteJ8WCpkLcTudkAB+anWYrOVlnVx4gnIOik1HZJIPJ4vSGKZAGEJEAwXQwXbKjegUel0igsdYTN5gVUkIA

Comment: @pingeyeg Please press run and tell me if that is that your desired output.

Comment: I'm seeing `No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'FakeObj'`.  That's also what I get locally, which is not allowing me to move forward with this.  However, the output is exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: @pingeyeg Well `Object.entries` returns `[key: string, value: any]`, and `string` cannot be used to index objects.

Comment: So, should I not be using reduce here?  Sorry, I'm a bit confused here and just trying to figure out the best solution.  My objective is to fill in the null values on objectOne with the values from objectTwo.

Comment: @pingeyeg Well, yes. I don't think reduce should be used. But I'm generally not a fan of it. But I added a new portion of code to my answer to make it work. But I have a question to you. Why are objectOne and objectTwo arrays? It would be way easier if they were not, and you're just trying to fill the missing properties.

Comment: Hah, that is a good question indeed.  It's kind of a complicated answer, but I'm receiving these arrays from the BE and have to manipulate them to work with them for the FE.

Comment: @pingeyeg Are you trying to fill the entry of the first array with the same indexed entry of the second?

Comment: Basically, I want objectOne to have its null values replaced with the good values from objectTwo.

Comment: @pingeyeg So you receive an array but it is always one entry?

Comment: I have two endpoints that send me two of the same object, only one has more null's than the other so I'm trying to merge the two to replace as many null values as possible and end up with a single object.  Silly, I know, but it's what I'm dealing with.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235758/discussion-between-elias-and-pingeyeg).

Comment: @pingeyeg if you care to fix your problem, please join me in the above mentioned chat :)

Comment: let me know when you have a moment.

Comment: @pingeyeg btw I wrote you in the chat in case you don't get notifications :)

Comment: All good, I'll revisit this another time.  We've decided to postpone this for now.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: @pingeyeg Alright, just @ me, I don't think it is a hard problem tbh :)